# Any way to implement batch put along with checkAndPut in HBase

Tags: hbase

I was working on writing to HBase clusters. I have to write only if data is not present hence I use the `checkAndPut()`. But the performance is poor when compared to `put(List<Put>)`. Is there any way I can combine the two operations? I tried to look around but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 6):

When you use `checkAndPut()` you do one RPC-call per request. So, you can't achieve performance more then `1 / rtt` requests per second (rtt is Round Trip Time). If you have rtt 1ms between your client and region server, your theoretical maximum is 1000 rps. When using batch operations like `put(List<Put>)` you need a lot less RPC-calls causing performance increase. I see two methods of problem solving:

1. Use pool of workers to parallel requests. You may find useful `HTablePool` class for managing connections in workers.
2. If you don't need to know about operation status (new cell inserted or old cell remains), you may try to write coprocessor that silently drops put requests in case of cell existence. In this case, if you need to replace some cell, you must delete it first.